# How to convert varchar to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I would like to convert `varchar` data to `datetime` format. So, can anyone let me know the way. this is the sample data available in column.

[image]

I tried following things

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [EntryTime] = '' 
       THEN NULL 
       ELSE CONVERT(datetime2, [EntryTime]) 
    END [EntryTime] 
FROM
    table
```

I get this result:

[image]

But, I don't need additional milliseconds.

So, can anyone let me know how should I convert it to a `datetime` format?

For all other tries, I am getting error as

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

So, can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: please specify sql-server version in your questions, as you see below it does actually matter (use the tags for this)

Answer (score 0):

specify the sub-second width as datetime2(7)

```
select
       try_cast(EntryTime as datetime2(7))    by_try_cast
     , try_convert(datetime2(7), EntryTime )  by_try_covert
```

I also suggest you use try_cast() or try_convert() if they are available, if not just remove "try_", The advantage of these is that if a string is an invalid date they return NULL and don't crash the query.

If you really don't want datetime2:

```
select cast(try_cast(EntryTime as datetime2(7)) as datetime)
```

see it: http://rextester.com/YWBB31287

Comment: just a note: SQL Server (starting with 2012) and Azure SQL Database for try_cast/convert

Comment: @maSTAShuFu thank you (& they are definitely worth using if you have a version where they are available)

Comment: it is very clever.

Answer (score -1):

LEFT and Concat (SQL2012+)/ or use standard concatenation 
then Cast or Convert (for formatting)

```
declare @mytable as table (
entrytime varchar(100)
)

insert into @mytable
values ('2017-08-31 08:23:23'),
('2017-11-10 08:28:37.75000000'),
('2017-10-30 08:23:37.32000000')


select cast(left(concat(entrytime,'.000'),23) as datetime) from @mytable
```

Result

```
2017-08-31 08:23:23.000
2017-11-10 08:28:37.750
2017-10-30 08:23:37.320
```